# is this an actual crash or virtual crash for ios ? and what could be reason behind this crash?

Tags: ios

0
Crashed: WebThread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000001

```
libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient
1   AGXGLDriver (null)
2   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib  gpusSubmitDataBuffers
3AGXGLDriver    (null)
4   WebCore WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::reshape(int, int) + 528
5 WebCore   WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::initializeNewContext() + 716
6   WebCore 
WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::WebGLRenderingContextBase(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement&, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>&&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 544
7   WebCore 
WebCore::WebGLRenderingContext::WebGLRenderingContext(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::GraphicsContext3D>, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes) + 60
8   WebCore 
WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::create(WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes&, WTF::String const&) + 1176
9   WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement::getContextWebGL(WTF::String const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext3DAttributes&&) + 156
10  WebCore 
WebCore::JSHTMLCanvasElement::getContext(JSC::ExecState&) + 360
11  WebCore 
WebCore::jsHTMLCanvasElementPrototypeFunctionGetContext(JSC::ExecState*) + 172
12  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 28916
13  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
14  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
15  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
16  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
17  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
18  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
19  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
20  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
21  JavaScriptCore  
vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
22  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 164
23  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 416
24  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::boundFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 552
25  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 28916
26  JavaScriptCore  
llint_entry + 26408
27  JavaScriptCore  
vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
28  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 164
29  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 416
30  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 164
31  JavaScriptCore  
JSC::JSJobMicrotask::run(JSC::ExecState*) + 436
32  WebCore 
WebCore::JSDOMWindowMicrotaskCallback::call() + 152
33  WebCore 
WebCore::ActiveDOMCallbackMicrotask::run() + 48
34  WebCore 
WebCore::MicrotaskQueue::performMicrotaskCheckpoint() + 100
35  WebCore 
WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&, WebCore::ExceptionDetails*) + 352
36  WebCore 
WebCore::ScriptElement::executeClassicScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 548
37  WebCore 
WebCore::LoadableClassicScript::execute(WebCore::ScriptElement&) + 52
38  WebCore 
WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScriptAndDispatchEvent(WebCore::LoadableScript&) + 216
39  WebCore 
WebCore::ScriptRunner::timerFired() + 504
40  WebCore 
WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 172
41  WebCore 
WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
42  CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
43  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 856
44  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopDoTimers + 244
45  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopRun + 1484
46  CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
47  WebCore 
RunWebThread(void*) + 456
48  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
_pthread_body + 240
49  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
_pthread_body + 282
50
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
thread_start + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a crash. If you want further help please provide the code that caused this error.

Comment: i don't have related code, this crash i am getting from third party sdk. i got this logs from fabric.

Comment: Ok. Remember: the more information you can provide the easier it is to help you figure things out. I've never worked with fabric so I hope someone else can help you further. 